# Files from sub directories

Tags: vb.net

Can somebody help me to implement to add files from sub directories to my listbox ? I have looked for some information from google, but source code from those examples was really diffrent than my and I'm newbie in VB.NET. I think it may be the System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories but I have no clue how to implement it in my code.

```
    Private Sub ButtonFolder_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonFolder.Click
    FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
    FilePathLabel.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
    Dim folder As New IO.DirectoryInfo(System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath))
    Dim arrfile() As IO.FileInfo
    Dim file As IO.FileInfo
    arrfile = folder.GetFiles("*.*")
    dicPaths.Clear()
    For Each file In arrfile
        'ListBox1.Items.Add(file.FullName)
        dicPaths.Add(file.Name, file.FullName)
    Next file
    For Each item As String In dicPaths.Keys
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item)
    Next item
    Label1.Text = "Total Items : " + ListBox1.Items.Count.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: What problem behavior are you observing? An exception? No exception, but no visible changes in the UI?

Comment: I dont have any exception. He is loading all files from directory without any problem. But now I want to make step forward and to get all files from directory + files from sub directories .

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Public Function FindFiles(ByVal Path As String) As Boolean
Dim Directories As New IO.DirectoryInfo(Path)
Dim Directory As IO.DirectoryInfo
Dim File As IO.FileInfo
For Each Directory In Directories.GetDirectories
For Each File In Directory.GetFiles
ListBox1.Items.Add(File.Name)
Next

If Directory.GetDirectories.Length > 0 Then
FindFiles(Directory.FullName)
End If
Next
End Function
```

Usage: `FindFiles(FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)`

Comment: @newbie If the answer helped you, you can mark it as the answer.